# Configure ESLint that optional parameters in brackets

Tags: typescript, eslint, jsdoc, typescript-eslint

How can I configure ESLint so that it checks that required parameters are written in JSDoc without brackets, and optional parameters are written in brackets?

Example

```
/**
 * Function params
 *
 * @property param1    good
 * @property [param2]  good
 * @property param3    bad
 * @property [param4]  bad
 */
interface Props {
  param1: boolean;
  param2?: boolean;
  param3?: boolean;
  param4: boolean;
}
```

Comment: To make that work you'd need both type information from TypeScript _and_ JSDoc parsing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ESLint rule in common use to do what you're asking for. Using both `@property` and typeScript isn't generally a practice TypeScript developers generally go for:

- TypeScript types already describe whether properties are optional, using `?`
- JSDoc descriptions of interface properties generally go on the properties themselves

The interface from the question would likely be written more like:

```
/**
 * Function params
 */
interface Props {
  /**
   * Either a multi-line comment...
   */
  param1: boolean;

  /**
   * Either a multi-line comment...
   */
  param2?: boolean;

  /** Or a single-line one. */
  param3?: boolean;

  /** Or a single-line one. */
  param4: boolean;
}
```

If you really want an ESLint rule to enforce the requested behavior you could write it using the APIs described in [typescript-eslint > Docs > Custom Rules](https://typescript-eslint.io/developers/custom-rules). See also [eslint-plugin-jsdoc](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc) for examples of other JSDoc rules.